# Reference request for multiple free sequences

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, integer-sequences

Erdos usually named a sequence of integers no one of which is divisible by any other as an $M$- sequence (M stands for "multiple-free") or *primitive sequence*.

For example it is easy to see that $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor+1, \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor+2, \ldots ,n-1, n$  is an $M$- sequence with terms not greater than $n$. Actually we cannot hope from an $M$- sequence to contain more than half of the numbers $\le n$  as Erdos has proved.
My question is:
Are there other examples of non trivial $M$-sequences (prime numbers, squares of primes, etc) in the literature which we can form ***explicitly***?

Answer (score 1):

The set $P_k(n)$ defined by
$$
P_k(n)=\{a: 1<a \leq n, \Omega(a)=k \}, \quad k\geq 1
$$
where $\Omega(a)$ counts the number of distinct prime divisors with multiplicity is one such set for each fixed $k.$ Thus $P_2(n)$ is the set of integers in $(1,n]$ which have exactly two prime divisors. The cardinality of these sets can be estimated from the prime number theorem.

Hall's book "Multiples" is a good reference for this.

Comment: You don't want that $\omega(a)$ in there, do you?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks for that, fixed.